# How to show message like "the application has crashed, but a report is sent to the admin" in android

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

I am new to android and my application involves lot of internet access and many times when the data that needs to come from a web service is unavailable my application crashes.

I tried to avoid as many cases as possible, but i am not sure if my application is crash free.

I am using an application named "delight circle" and sometimes that application crashes and shows me this Toast:

"The application has crashed and a report is sent to the admin"

and takes me back to the previous activity or previous action, and from here i can use the application normally again.

I have 2 questions:

1. How to make the application work normally after it crashes once. In my application, if it crashes then it asks me for force close and when i click it, it takes me to the previous activity(or action) but nothing works there, if i try to do anything it asks for force close again, i eventually end up force closing the application from Settings --> Applications --> myApp --> foce close.
2. How to send a report about what actually caused the application to crash?? Right now i have a lot of logs in every activity so, now if it crashes i can find out the exact reason and solve. But when i release the application how can i do this?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [UnCaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for this.

Here is a example,

http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/

Once you override the Exception Handler, you will be provided with access to the Log and from where, either you can send the error log which you get the from the SatckTrace as an Email or use Apis to do it.

Comment: Okay thank you, i will check the link you posted. But regarding the Logs, i will get the stacktrace like "null pointer exception" or "index out of bounds exception" etc??? or can i have my Logs. Actually i want to know if i should keep the Logs i am using or remove them before release

Comment: You should never have your Logs printed. You have to remove them for security reasons. And from the StackTrace you will be getting the line which is causing the Exception and with the kind of Exception itself. So shouldn't be a problem. And also by removing the Logs you can definitely save some time and improve the speed of the app(works when there are huge logs to be printed).

Comment: but if i get a report as "NullPointerException in SomeActivity" i will not be able to understand what action or series or actions caused such an exception right?? even if i want to debug depending on which activity the exception occured, i may not know what set of or series of actions caused that exception

Answer (score 2):

I can give an answer to your second question, that is "*How to send a report about what actually caused the application to crash*" Try **[Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/)** in your code. It will help you to find the exact cause of failing the application. Not only that, it has so many features, like Live Stats, Unresolved crashes, Crash alarms and more.